# Simple no frameworks Node.JS server to host a SPA React App

Tags: node.js

Here on the the create-react-app site we find an `Express` tutorial to host a SPA React App (notice the `*` to return single `index.html` at every valid path request):

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(9000);
```

Is there a way to replicate this behaviour on pure `Node.js`, without frameworks? The way it would handle every valid path, but respond with an error when the path do not exist, etc.. I did not find any information about doing this, is this possible to do with not too much of code or forking `Express`?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? just not have express and use node js' `http` library? Do you even need node? just use nginx

Comment: Just don't use `/*`, it will catch all requests and return your `index.html`. Use only your valid paths, and your invalid ones will get errors :D

Comment: @azium I am building a rest api and want to deploy my React SPA using pure node.

Comment: What is "pure node"? Do you think express is not pure for some reason?

Comment: @OmriAttiya but how so I determine if the path is valid if I have one `index.html`? I could handle wrong paths in my react app end tho. But the other problem is I can't respond as html to everything, cause I need to respond with media and assets too.

Comment: @azium no, I just mean without using any frameworks. Want to try this way (as a challange in some way), cause my app won't be much complicated.

Comment: @John You have [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) examples of how to do it. Just define a pattern for assets. You can also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539210/express-js-handle-unmached-routes) how to handle invalid routes.

Comment: ok well here's the node doumentation for `http` you can do everything you need with it https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is: respond to any `GET` requests that do not match your MIME types or have no extention, with `index.html` and handle `404` requests on your front-end.

I followed my lecturer lection and source code - https://github.com/HowProgrammingWorks/ServeStatic - and modified it a little bit to work with `React SPA`. Posting simplified code here, I hope you get the idea:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');

// postOrder and updateJson are predifined async fucntions.
const postTypes = {
  '/api/order': postOrder,
  '/api/update_json': updateJson,
};

const STATIC_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), './public');

const MIME_TYPES = {
  html: 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  js: 'application/javascript; charset=UTF-8',
  css: 'text/css',
  json: 'application/json',
  png: 'image/png',
  jpg: 'image/jpeg',
  jpeg: 'image/jpeg',
  ico: 'image/x-icon',
  svg: 'image/svg+xml',
};

const serveFile = name => {
  const filePath = path.join(STATIC_PATH, name);
  if (!filePath.startsWith(STATIC_PATH)) {
    console.log(`Can't be served: ${name}`);
    return null;
  }
  const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
  console.log(`Served: ${name}`);
  return stream;
};

http
  .createServer(async (req, res) => {
    const { url } = req;
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
      const fileExt = path.extname(url).substring(1);
      const mimeType = MIME_TYPES[fileExt] || MIME_TYPES.html;
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': mimeType });
      const stream = fileExt === '' ? serveFile('/index.html') : serveFile(url);
      if (stream) stream.pipe(res);
    } else if (req.method === 'POST') {
      const postType = postTypes[url];
      let response = postType ? await postType(req) : `Woops, no ${url} post type!`;
      res.writeHead(response ? 200 : 500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
      response ||= `Woops, your response failed to arrive!`;
      res.end(response);
    }
  })
  .listen(3000);
```